# Only few files being extracted using node.js unzip modules

Tags: node.js, unzip

I've been using Unzip library in NodeJS, however, only few files are being extracted, and on each execution the files extracted are different

```
fs.createReadStream('test.zip').pipe(unzipper.Extract({ path: 'test' })
.on('finish', function() { 
  console.log("finish")
})
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

To fix the above issue, I had to implement the below instead of the code posted in the question

```
fs.createReadStream("test.zip").on("error", log).pipe(unzipper.Parse()).on("entry", function (entry) {
    var isDir = entry.type === "Directory";
    var fullpath = path.join(dest, entry.path);
    // console.log("fullpath ", fullpath)
    var directory = isDir ? fullpath : path.dirname(fullpath);
    mkdirp(directory, function (err) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        if (!isDir) {
            entry.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fullpath));
        }
    })
        .on("close", function (message) {
            console.log("close");
            resolve("/DEST")
        }).on("finish", function (message) {
            console.log("finish");
            resolve("/DEST")
        });
});
```